# VMWare SDK C# VirtualMachine Interface Type

Tags: c#, vmware

I have code that gets the virtualmachine network connections and retrieves the connected switch information.

The code I have seems to work for "VirtualEthernetCardNetworkBackingInfo" type interfaces, but this fails when a server is connected to the VD Switch as one needs to use the "VirtualEthernetCardDistributedVirtualPortBackingInfo" type in that scenario.

Question is, how do you detect the interface type before you try to cast the object? Or should one just try to cast and see which one works?

This is the code I have but I'm looking for something cleaner...

```
bool vswitch = false, vds = false;

VirtualEthernetCard _workloadnic = (VirtualEthernetCard)_virtualdevice;
//first check if the VM is connected to a vswitch
try
{
    VirtualEthernetCardNetworkBackingInfo _nic_backing = (VirtualEthernetCardNetworkBackingInfo)_workloadnic.Backing;
    network_moid = _nic_backing.Network.Value;
    vswitch = true;
}
catch (Exception ex) { }

//if it was not a vswitch it should be a vds
if (!vswitch)
{
    try
    {
        VirtualEthernetCardDistributedVirtualPortBackingInfo _nic_backing = (VirtualEthernetCardDistributedVirtualPortBackingInfo)_workloadnic.Backing;
        network_moid = _nic_backing.Port.SwitchUuid
        vds = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
}
if (!vswitch || !vds)
{
    Logger.log(String.Format("UpdateVMwareWorkload: Could not determine workload network backing type"), Logger.Severity.Error);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It think this will work just fine...

```
            if (_workloadnic.Backing is VirtualEthernetCardNetworkBackingInfo)
            {

            }
            else if (_workloadnic.Backing is VirtualEthernetCardDistributedVirtualPortBackingInfo)
            {

            }
```